# How to create a setup file for a project that was written in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, installation

I have created a GUI application using Netbeans and it has a connection to a database( localhost).

Now I want to be able to distribute it as software.

Is there any way to produce a setup file for the Netbeans project? and how can I distribute a Netbeans project which uses a MySQL database?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to ship jre with your code ?

Comment: may be yes, because every computer not installed jre. If there is possible way to do this without shipping jre it's ok..

Comment: @DiniduKariyawasam No, its not possible to run your java program if there is no java installed.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I distribute a Netbeans project which uses a MySQL database?

You might want to get familiar with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).  NSIS will enable you to automate the installation process.

Your installation process will have to do the following:

- Check that the Java Runtime Environment is the same version you used or higher.
- Install your application JAR file somewhere.
- Install the MySQL version that your application requires
- Create and initialize the tables for your application.

Your installation process can do the following:

- Create an uninstall executable.
- Add an icon so that the user can start your application.

This installation process will take some time to develop and test.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an installer. Have a look at:

- [Install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html)
- [Installshield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) (commercial)
- [Advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) if you target only windows platforms

There are many others but I hope this can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution made by the suppliers of Java - [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

- The `deployJava.js` (described in the linked page) ensures the user has the minimum JRE needed to launch the app. & MySQL.
- Launch the app. using Java Web Start.

  - Reference an `installer-desc` extension for installing the DB.  Store any set-up details into the `PersistenceService` for later use.

JWS works on all major platforms for which J2SE is available and also provides..

> ..many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..